# Loading in Background in iOS. Nativescript

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have to download a large amount of data from the server and continue doing it in the background even when the user hides my app (sample: when you install a app from Play Market, you can switch to another app and loading continues) in my iOS nativescript-angular application. How can I do this? Can I use Angular Services for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion on this.A Worker is different from Background Service. A work just helps you to move your load from main / UI thread into a different thread. But you need a Background Service when you want to fetch location & upload data in background even when your app is minimised / killed.

[nativescript-geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation) plugin itself has an example for [fetching location in background](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/background-service.ts), you may use the similar approach and upload data to server instead of showing it in a toast as in the example.

For iOS, you should use the geo location plugin and subscribe for updates in background using [Background Fetch](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/backgroundexecution). Instead of `UIBackgroundModes` as `fetch` you should use `location`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it will help me. But can you explain in more detail why I should use location instead of fetch?